# Change key bindings in TeXworks

Tags: texworks

Some of default key bindings in TeXworks are completely unusable for me. I use a German keyboard and the comment keys are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, which on my keyboard can only be realized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>. This however is not accepted by TeXworks.

However I could not find any way to change the key binding. Is this configurable somehow?

Further I would like to have "% " (percent plus space).

I use TeXworks for editing `.dtx` files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts can be changed by creating a file called `shortcuts.ini` placed in the TeXworks resources folder, in the subfolder called `configuration`. The file can contain specifications of keyboard shortcuts.

If you don't know where the resources folder is, open TeXworks and go to Help -> Settings and resources.

For the syntax used in the file, see section A.2 *Keyboard shortcuts* in the manual, found at https://github.com/TeXworks/manual/releases

Answer (score 0):

Here Texworks 0.6.4.

There are some possibilities to customize the key bindings, but not all editing possibilities are shortlisted for customization.

I have looked into the manual (last version 15 March 2020) at https://github.com/TeXworks/manual/releases/download/2020-03-15/TeXworks-manual-en.pdf#page43 and appendix A.2 talks keyboard shortcuts and lists the permissible actions.

In my case I would have loved to have a shortcut to shift lines up and down, as gedit does with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Up/Down</kbd>.

Comment: Oops, I just edited my answer following your comment.

Comment: Regarding moving lines up and down, in order to have a keyboard shortcut for it, the feature has to exist in the editor. That might not be the case, but you could post a feature request on GitHub.