# Insert code snippet via keyboard shortcut in TeXworks

Tags: macros, texworks, keywords, keyboard

I know there already are questions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31541/change-key-bindings-in-texworks/31543#31543), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22481/can-i-configure-shortcut-keys-in-texworks/22482#22482)) on creating keyboard shortcuts in TeXworks. The discussion (also in the Google thread referred to), however, seems a little outdated.

By now, there is the possibility to create keyboard shortcuts via the `shortcuts.ini` file ([link](http://www.leliseron.org/texworks/)) as well as keywords via adding a `.txt` file to the `completion` folder ([link](http://texworks.googlecode.com/files/TeXworks-manual-r814.pdf), p.23).

What I am trying to achieve is: create a keyboard shortcut (say, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) which inserts a code snippet such as `\vec{#INS#}•` (which would insert the snippet `\vec{}`, move the cursor to `#INS#` and add a placeholder at `•`).

While the first part (create a keyboard shortcut for some command) as well as the second one (create a keyword which expands to the full snippet) can be carried out separately, I can't get the combination to work - I only figured how to add shortcuts for commands listed at the bottom of [this](http://www.leliseron.org/texworks/) explanation.

Any help on how to perform the desired task would be appreciated. If my question is not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I fancied a challenge answering an ancient question with no answers or comments. This is possible using scripts within TeXWorks (note: I have a [custom dark theme for TeXWorks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660190/273733) hence the background):

[image]

The steps to create a custom command (in your case `\vec{}`) mapped to a keyboard shortcut (in your case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>):

1. From file explorer, go to: `C:\Users\[Your User]\.texlive2022\texmf-config\texworks\scripts` on Windows and its equivalent on Linux or Mac (I only use Windows so do not know exactly).
2. Your folder should look similar to this (assuming you do not already have custom scripts):

[image]

3. Within `\.texlive2022\texmf-config\texworks\scripts`, create a new folder name "Custom" or something similar.
4. Open notepad or an equivalent plain-text programme, name it `vec.js` (needs to be .js, javascript. Can be named whatever you desire as long as it is unique) and save it within `/scripts/Custom/`.
5. Right click and edit with whatever text programme you desire `vec.js` and paste the following into it (credit for the .js `addOrRemove` code is with Jonathan Kew):

```
// TeXworksScript
// Title: vec
// Description: Inserts \vec{} into text
// Author: JamesT (based on work by Jonathan Kew)
// Version: 0.1
// Date: 2022-02-16
// Script-Type: standalone
// Context: TeXDocument
// Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+v

function addOrRemove(prefix, suffix) {
  var txt = TW.target.selection;
  var len = txt.length;
  var wrapped = prefix + txt + suffix;
  var pos = TW.target.selectionStart;
  if (pos >= prefix.length) {
    TW.target.selectRange(pos - prefix.length, wrapped.length);
    if (TW.target.selection === wrapped) {
      TW.target.insertText(txt);
      TW.target.selectRange(pos - prefix.length, len);
      return;
    }
    TW.target.selectRange(pos, len);
  }
  TW.target.insertText(wrapped);
  TW.target.selectRange(pos + prefix.length, len);
  return;
}

addOrRemove("\\vec{", "}•");
```

6. Save and close the `vec.js` folder. Open TeXWorks and navigate to the `Scripts` -> `Custom` folder to verify that it has been created:

[image]

7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to verify it has worked.

This is how you can insert code snippets via keyboard shortcuts in TeXWorks and it looks very useful now I know how to do it too, good question!